# Multiple Authentication Provider and Multiple Entry Points

Tags: authentication, jwt, microservices, jhipster

I am developing an Jhipster microservices application using the Jhipster UAA with JWT. All the the login and access the other microservices work fine. However, I have a requirement for some set of users to able to use a different custom authentication provider for gaining access.

So the flow is like the following:

```
ADMIN users: ---> default UAA auth provider ---> access to entire app (including /api/**)
MOBILE users: --> custom auth provider ---> access /api/** for allowed roles
```

Does Jhipster allow this? How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

I would go with 2 gateways: one for admin users and one for mobile users, then in microservices I would support the 2 kind of auth tokens based on the issuer and this requires writing custom code using Spring Security.

Comment: Is there any other option (or even a workaround) you could suggest (hint)? thanks